# Nested API Calls in React with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've searched quite a few forums and articles but still have yet to get this code to work. I'm able to log out the proper data but for some reason when I try to set the State I get an empty object. I've been at this for a few hours now so it's quite possible I have missed something simple.

In the code block below, `console.log(tempOwnership)` works as it should (array of dictionary objects), but `setOwnerData(tempOwnership)` doesn't seem to have the proper effect as nothing renders to the DOM. If I comment out this line "mechanical" renders as it should since this is the default State.

```js
import './index.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { DTSummaryAPI, OwnershipAPI, OwnershipDomainAPI, UserAPI } from 'src/apis/designtrack';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function DTSummary() {
  let {id} = useParams();
  
  const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState("Loading");
  const [ownerData, setOwnerData] = useState([{"domain": "mechanical"}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchOwnershipData(id)
    fetchSummaryData(id)
  }, [])

  const fetchSummaryData = async (id) => {
    try{
      const response = await DTSummaryAPI.getById(id)
      setSummaryData(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const fetchOwnershipData = async (id) => {
    let tempOwnership = []
    try {
      const results = await OwnershipAPI.getByDt(id)
      results.data.forEach(element => {
        fetchOwnerData(element.domain, element.user)
        .then(data => {
          tempOwnership.push(data);
        }).catch(error => {console.log(error);});
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(tempOwnership)
    setOwnerData(tempOwnership)
  } 

  const fetchOwnerData = async(domainId, userId) => {
    let ownership = {}
    await axios.all(
      [
        OwnershipDomainAPI.getById(domainId),
        UserAPI.getById(userId)
      ]).then(axios.spread((domain, user) => {
        ownership["domain"] = domain.data.name
        ownership["username"] = userId
        ownership["firstname"] = user.data.firstname
        ownership["lastname"] = user.data.surname
      })).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
      return ownership
  }
  

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8">
          <h1>{summaryData.title}</h1>
          <div>
            {ownerData.map((items, index) => {
              return <p key={index}>{items.domain}</p>
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <h1>Thumbnail</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default DTSummary;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the forEach loop with a standard for loop, and the fetchOwnerData call is now awaited directly within the loop to ensure proper asynchronous behavior.

```
const fetchOwnershipData = async (id) => {
  let tempOwnership = [];
  try {
    const results = await OwnershipAPI.getByDt(id);
    for (let i = 0; i < results.data.length; i++) {
      const element = results.data[i];
      try {
        const data = await fetchOwnerData(element.domain, element.user);
        tempOwnership.push(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(tempOwnership);
  setOwnerData(tempOwnership);
};
```

Comment: Lovely! Why does this one work but the above does not? It's strange to me that the `console.log(tempOwnership)` worked but the very next line `setOwnerData(tempOwnership)` did not.